# In mariadb the Count(*) AS something doesn't work. Is there a better way to express this?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

The current mariadb does not allow the following code the COUNT(*) AS something.
Is there anyway to resolve this please.

```
$db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS msgCount FROM messages');
```

Comment: I believe it does allow it. I have no problem running the query. What error do you get, what version of Mariadb are you running. We need more info than just: "it doesn't work".

Comment: I am using mariadb version 10.4.10. The error it gives is 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'msgCount FROM messages

Comment: What is you run this query directly, without preparing? And if you run the query using phpAdmin or directly in the Mariadb CLI, do you get same error?

Comment: it works alright then

Comment: Replace `AS` and the spaces around it.  It may not actually be what it looks like -- as in a 'hard' space instead of a regular blank.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the help you provided especially to Maarten. I went back to the command line and tried them for myself. What I was missing is the quotation mark around it.

```
$db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS "msgCount" FROM messages');
```

It wasn't working for me until I added that. I saw that from: https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/functions/count.php
Look at their example with single expression. That was when it worked for me.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of Sites"
FROM sites
WHERE site_name in ('TechOnTheNet.com', 'CheckYourMath.com');
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. There's no need for double quotes. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b7185e5b6645ef48e374bb611d45f425